# php form populating from mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a page that shows information from my database. Each array has an edit link that has a unic id (.html?id=4).

The problem:
The form I created to query the database based on the id results in no information being displayed?

Any idea what I need to do to accomplish this?

```
<?php
    // Connect to the database
require 'include/episodelist.db.php';
    // Ask the database for the information from the table based on .html?id=#
$query="SELECT * FROM `season` WHERE `id` = $id";
    //The above query is the problem.
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'season'");
mysql_close();
?>
<form action="include/epslist.edit.php" method="POST">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Season Number: </td><td><input type="text" name="season_sum" size="50" value="<?php echo "$season_num";?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Episode Number: </td><td><input type="text" name="eps_num" size="50" value="<?php echo "$eps_num";?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Temp Episode Number: </td><td><input type="text" name="temp_eps_num" size="50" value="<?php echo "$temp_eps_num";?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Title: </td><td><input type="text" name="title" size="50" value="<?php echo "$title";?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Description: </td><td><textarea type="text" name="descrip" cols="50" rows="7" value="<?php echo "$descrip";?>"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<input type="Submit" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>
</table></form>
```

Comment: As far as I can see in the code you posted, you are not giving any value to `$id` variable

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient MySQL extension: it is no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should use either the improved [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) extension or the [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) abstraction layer. Also don't put variables (especially those which come from your user) into your SQL, as it makes you vulnerable to SQL injection. You should instead use prepared statements, with which your variables can be passed to MySQL as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.

Comment: you forgot to fetch the id from the get request $id = $_GET['id'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the form has the $id passed as a variable, if so, get the $id and populate the fields with data from the database. If not, show a blank form.

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
   // Get ID
   $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

   // Do query and save data to array
   $query="SELECT * FROM `season` WHERE `id` = $id";
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'season'");
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

   $fields = array('seasonid'    => $row['seasonid'],
                   'episodenum'  => $row['episodenum']
   );

   mysql_close();

}
else
{

   // No id, use blank values
   $fields = array('seasonid'    => '',
                   'episodenum'  => ''
   );
}

?>

<!-- Populate form with fields array -->
...
<td>Season Number: </td><td><input type="text" name="season_sum" size="50" value="<?php echo($fields['seasonid']); ?>"></td>
...
```

Of course, use of mysql this way lends to security concerns and is headed in the direction of deprecation. [PDO](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (PHP Data Objects) is the way to go for handling database operations. Usage of PDO allows prepared statements/parameterized queries and looks something like this:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
   $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
   echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
} 

$id = $_GET['id'];

// Use a prepared statement to avoid SQL injection
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM `season` WHERE `id` = :id');
$sth->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: I am trying out your code. Please give me a moment. Sorry that I know less about PDO then I do about MySql. Ill look into it though. Right now I will be happy if I can just get the fields to populate based on the edit link I clicked :)

Comment: So no joy. The link in the address bar is passing the id.  [EXAMPE] test.html/id=4      When I click the link im directed to the form page on test.html but non of id's 4 info gets populated into the form fields for updating. They all remain blank?

Comment: I don't use the mysql_* functions anymore so I accidentally missed using the `mysql_fetch_assoc()` function. And also, I don't know what your database fields are named so make sure you use the correct values. That is more of an example than anything.

Comment: Why were you passing variables  like `html/id=4` ... It should be `html?id=4`

Comment: opps, no its .html?id=4 thats my goof putting in the / in my comment here.

Comment: Sadly I am still not getting the fields to populate. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20618553/phpcode1.txt here is a link to the code as it stands. Any idea what could still be wrong?

Comment: Good news, I was able to get the filed to populate with a bit of tweaking of the code you gave me. Thanks for all your help everyone.